# Anaconda reading wrong CUDA version

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, conda, torch

I have a conda environment with PyTorch and Tensorflow, which both require CUDA 9.0 (~cudatoolkit 9.0 from conda). After installing pytorch with torchvision and the cudatoolkit (like they provided on their website) I wanted to install Tensorflow, the problem here is that I get this error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                   

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - tensorflow==1.12.0 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.6.*']
  - tensorflow==1.12.0 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.5

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==10.2=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==10.2=0

Your installed version is: 10.2
```

If I run `nvcc` or `nvidia-smi` on my host or the activated conda environment, I get that I have installed CUDA 10.2, even though `conda list` shows me that cudatoolkit 9.0 is installed. Any solution to this?

EDIT:

When running this code sample:

```
# setting device on GPU if available, else CPU
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print('Using device:', device)
print()

#Additional Info when using cuda
if device.type == 'cuda':
    print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
    print('Memory Usage:')
    print('Allocated:', round(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)/1024**3,1), 'GB')
    print('Cached:   ', round(torch.cuda.memory_cached(0)/1024**3,1), 'GB')


print(torch.version.cuda)
```

I get this output:

```
GeForce GTX 1050
Memory Usage:
Allocated: 0.0 GB
Cached:    0.0 GB
9.0.176
```

So PyTorch does get the correct CUDA version, I just cant get tensorflow-gpu installed.

Comment: EDIT: I'm running a mobile 1050 with the driver version 440.100.

Comment: Just as a note, don't use StackSnippets for things other than HTML, CSS, and JS. Especially don't put Python in the Javascript section. It takes up more space in the question, and it produces errors when run, anyway. For now, I've suggested an edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I run `nvcc` or `nvidia-smi` on my host or the activated `conda` environment, I get that I have installed `CUDA 10.2`, even though `conda list` shows me that `cudatoolkit 9.0` is installed. Any solution to this?

`cudatoolkit` doesn't ship with compiler (`nvcc`), thus when you run `nvcc` you start compiler from system wide installation. That's why it prints `10.2` istead of `9.0`, and `pytorch` sees the local `cudatoolkit`.

[anaconda / packages / cudatoolkit](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cudatoolkit) :

> This CUDA Toolkit includes GPU-accelerated libraries, and the CUDA runtime for the Conda ecosystem. For the full CUDA Toolkit with a compiler and development tools visit https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

From your comment above I understood that you are using `python=3.5.6`. So, first of all you should search for available `tensorflow` `py35` builds using:

```sh
conda search tensorflow | grep py35
```

I have the following output:

```sh
tensorflow                     1.9.0 eigen_py35h8c89287_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0 gpu_py35h42d5ad8_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0 gpu_py35h60c0932_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0 gpu_py35hb39db67_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0 mkl_py35h5be851a_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 eigen_py35h5ed898b_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 gpu_py35h566a776_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 gpu_py35ha6119f3_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 gpu_py35hd9c640d_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 mkl_py35heddcb22_0  pkgs/main
```

As you can see there is no `tensorflow 1.12.0` builds for `py35`, and that's why you are getting that error. You can try to inspect other `conda` channels, for example, `conda-forge`:

```sh
conda search tensorflow -c conda-forge | grep py35
```

But that wasn't helpful:

```sh
tensorflow                     0.9.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                    0.10.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                 0.11.0rc0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                 0.11.0rc2          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                    0.11.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                    0.12.1          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                    0.12.1          py35_1  conda-forge         
tensorflow                    0.12.1          py35_2  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.0.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.1.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.2.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.2.1          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.3.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.4.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.5.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.5.1          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.6.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.8.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.8.0          py35_1  conda-forge         
tensorflow                     1.9.0 eigen_py35h8c89287_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0 gpu_py35h42d5ad8_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0 gpu_py35h60c0932_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0 gpu_py35hb39db67_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0 mkl_py35h5be851a_1  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                     1.9.0          py35_0  conda-forge         
tensorflow                    1.10.0 eigen_py35h5ed898b_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 gpu_py35h566a776_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 gpu_py35ha6119f3_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 gpu_py35hd9c640d_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0 mkl_py35heddcb22_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.10.0          py35_0  conda-forge
```

So, the possible solutions are:

1. Install one of the older available `tensorflow 1.10.0 gpu_py35` builds.
2. Switch to `python 3.6`.

```sh
conda search tensorflow | grep py36

...
tensorflow                    1.11.0 gpu_py36h4459f94_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.11.0 gpu_py36h9c9050a_0  pkgs/main           
...        
tensorflow                    1.12.0 gpu_py36he68c306_0  pkgs/main           
tensorflow                    1.12.0 gpu_py36he74679b_0  pkgs/main
...
```

**Note** that versions >=1.13.1 doesn't support `CUDA 9`.

3. Use `pip install` inside `conda` env to install missing `tensorflow` build, because `pip` hosts more build combinations: [Tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations)

Here is some best practices from Anaconda how to use `pip` w/ `conda`: [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment)

4. The last option is to build your own missing `conda` package with [`conda-build`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: but pip doesnt give you the benefit of using different cuda versions quickly on different parts of the system :/

Comment: Great!, BTW, I meant to use `pip install tensorflow` inside conda env and  not to replace `conda` w/ `pip`, just to be clear

Comment: Ah I see, but seems like a hack too don't you think?

Comment: @filip Actually, there is another option: to create conda package for missing software using `conda-build`. But I never had a chance to try it, in adition I'd like to recommend you this [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) post from anaconda

Comment: Thanks, will use when needed, python is really bad in comparison with npm package management wise. (okay, they don't have that many compiled packages like python (evermore in data science categories))

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that even though the detected cuda version is incorrect by conda, what matters is the cudatoolkit version.

The actual problem for me was the **incompatible python version**.
E.g. You might have Python 3.7/3.8 but this version of tensorflow doesn't support that:

> tensorflow==1.12.0 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Try an older conda environment or a newer tensorflow, the latest version before 2.0 is 1.15

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.6

Comment: Then this is a different problem.
I ended up installing both PyTorch and Tensorflow with cuda 10.0

Answer (score 1):

If I haven't misunderstood, you installed the packages using the

```
conda install
```

from https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
I once had problems with the conda installation of PyTorch and Cuda: i solved by removing the packages installed with conda and re-installing it via pip.

If you are afraid to mess up the conda enviroment using pip, I suggest you to create another enviroment in order to test this solution.

1. Use conda to remove pytorch and cuda. See *Removing Packages* at [Conda Managing packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#removing-packages)
2. Install the [cuda toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) you need. Note that pytorch supports only cuda 9.2, 10.1 and 10.2, as you can see on the Pytorch download page.
   If your OS is ubuntu 19, follow the CUDA instructions for ubuntu 18. Also note that not all gpus support the latest version of the toolkit for driver reasons (the 1050 should be recent enough to support them all, up to 10.1 sure because I used it).
3. Follow the instructions to install pytorch with the appropiate cuda support **via pip** at [Pytorch download page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). See *Using pip in an enviroment* at [Conda Managing packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=pip#using-pip-in-an-environment)

Comment: I currently went with installing it with pip, seems like a hack to me tho. I installed the packages myself, no requirements.txt or environment.yaml